# Testng delete test name data provider parameters

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I have the following problem

I have a test with a randomName, and I have to log two test params I provide from a DataProvider.

I have implemented a method to log them as custom processed test params by concatenating them into the name.

However TestNG also adds the params that are not processed (they look like random generated code with the name of the packages/classes and other things , you can see in the picture below.

[image]

Is there any way to remove the Data Provider test params logged by TestNG ? Or can I somehow overwrite them with my Custom Data Provider Test Params?

By the way, my custom test params are exactly the same with what TestNG is logging, I just want to remove the ones generated, and also the way I implemented my custom params is by implementing the ITest interface.

If there is any solution to this, please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is example how can change test name https://www.swtestacademy.com/change-test-name-testng-dataprovider/

Comment: I have managed to change the test name, the problem is the fact that I don't need the generated stuff before the test name. I want to delete the generated string.

Comment: @ib23 I have the same issue.. I want to remove all of the generated parameters and testNG always adds them as postfix

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove or clean up unnecessary parameters in your **@BeforeMethod**.

Here is an example of what solves my problem:

```java
package com.example.test;

import org.testng.ITest; 
import org.testng.ITestResult; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TestSetup implements ITest {
    public String testName = "";

    @BeforeMethod
    public void startTestLog(Method method, Object[] params, ITestResult result) {
        String dataProvider = method.getAnnotation(Test.class).dataProvider();

        testName = method.getAnnotation(Test.class).testName().isEmpty() ? method.getName() : method.getAnnotation(Test.class).testName();
        testName += (!dataProvider.isEmpty()) ? " [" + params[0].toString() + "]" : "";

        //remove parameters value from result
        result.setParameters(new Object[]{});
    }

    @Override
    public String getTestName() {
        return testName;
    } }
```